# undefined method `default_max_wait_time=' for Capybara:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: rspec, timeout, capybara, gemfile

I am getting this error

```
undefined method `default_max_wait_time=' for Capybara:Module (NoMethodError)
```

When I try to run feature specs, e.g.

$ rspec spec/features/auto_policies/3_step_minimal_foundation_spec.rb

```
...
Performance on MRI may be improved with the concurrent-ruby-ext gem. Please see http://concurrent-ruby.com ...
/Users/mdurrant/eq/lynx/spec/support/capybara.rb:69:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `default_max_wait_time=' for Capybara:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I have updated the Gemfile to the latest capybara (2.4.4) but I still get this message

How to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your capybara version 2.4.4, the method used is "`Capybara.default_wait_time`".
"`Capybara.default_wait_time`" was changed to "`Capybara.default_max_wait_time`" in version 2.5.0 as it more clearly explain its purpose.

So either you use "`Capybara.default_wait_time`" in you current version (2.4.4) or upgrade to 2.5.0 or above. The current latest version is 2.6.2, which is released on 27th Jan,2016. For more information refer to following link:
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/History.md

Answer (score 0):

`default_max_wait_time=` was added in 2.5.0. In 2.4.4, the method is still `default_wait_time=`

You will need to upgrade to a newer version. The latest is currently 2.6.2.